# Share custom validation method between given models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I want to share validation function between multiple models.
*Like components in controller.*

I think extending AppModel isnt an option, because the function isnt applicable to all of my Models, just 3 of them.

If possible I want to do it DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share methods between models in CakePHP use [Behaviors](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html) (the model equivalent of controller components).

You can do something like this to define your custom validation rules:-

```
// app/Model/Behavior/ValidateBehavior.php
class ValidateBehavior extends ModelBehavior {
    public function customValidationRule($Model, $data) {
        // some validation code
    }
}

// example model
class Example extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Validate');

    public $validate = array(
        'field' => array(
            'custom' => array(
                'rule' => array('customValidationRule')
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to create a function to validade in appModel and call betweenmodels or adding dinamicly ? [adding-your-own-validation-methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods)

or extend de validation class [core-validation-rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#core-validation-rules)

Comment: Yes, but according my question it isnt applicable.

It's not easy to override Validation, since its method are static and they're called in a static way (using the class name).